# Adding an array into a JSON struct in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash which looks as following (In Perl):

```
'multi' => {
           'key2' => '123',
           'key1' => 'abc',
           'key3' => 'xwz'
         }
```

Also I have the following structure:

```
my $json_struct = {
    name => $name,
    time => $time,
};
```

I would like to insert `multi` into the `$json_struct` as a array with keys and values. 
I use the `$json_struct` in order to convert it to a JSON file, so the JSON output should look as following:

```
{
    "name" : "some_name",
    "time" : "time",
    "multi" : [ 
    {
        "key" : "key1",
        "value" : "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "key" : "key2",
        "value" : "123"
    },
    {
        "key" : "key3",
        "value" : "xwz"
    }
],
}
```

How can I do it? What is the cleanest way possible (without importing additional modules).

Answer (score 1):

To add an array, you just add the reference to the array into your data structure:

```
$json_struct->{multi} = \@multi;
```

In the case that `%multi` is a hash, you can use:

```
my @multi = map { +{ key => $_, value => $multi{ $_ } } } sort keys %multi;
$json_struct->{multi} = \@multi;
```

#### See Also

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: Yes but `multi` is a hash, and it should be in a special format. Otherwise it would being easy

Comment: Then don't build up `multi` as a hash in the first place but keep it as an array. I've updated my answer to also cover the case of `multi` being a hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10.1;
use warnings FATAL => "all";
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

my $payload = {
    'multi' => {
        'key2' => '123',
        'key1' => 'abc',
        'key3' => 'xwz'
    }
};

my $json_struct = {
    name => "foo",
    time => "2018-12-03",
};

for my $key (keys %$payload) {
    my @as_array = map { 
        { 
            key => $_, 
            value => $payload->{$key}{$_} 
        } 
    } keys %{$payload->{$key}};
    $json_struct->{$key} = \@as_array;
}

say Dumper $json_struct;

# $VAR1 = {
#     'name' => 'foo',
#     'time' => '2018-12-03',
#     'multi' => [
#         {
#             'value' => 'abc',
#             'key' => 'key1'
#         },
#         {
#             'value' => '123',
#             'key' => 'key2'
#         },
#         {
#             'key' => 'key3',
#             'value' => 'xwz'
#         }
#     ]
# };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. does `$payload` works as a hash? for some reason it fails

Comment: "For some reason" is not helpful. Please tell us the exact error message you get.